# Why doesn't my AVFoundation Camera work on all devices?

Tags: swift, camera, avfoundation

I have an AVFoundation Custom Camera that works perfectly fine on my device and several others. On specific devices (iPhone 13 Pro Max & iPhone 11), it just shows a black screen, and when they press the capture button, the app crashes with the error `NSInvalidArgumentException - *** -[AVCapturePhotoOutput capturePhotoWithSettings:delegate:] No active and enabled video connection` . I'm at a loss because like I said, on my device and several others, the preview shows, and you can capture an image fine. I verified that both devices have allowed camera access for my app and I have errors set up for all the different types (denied, restricted, and unknown) but none of the alerts are triggered. Just a blank screen with the capture button that causes a crash.

UPDATE
I added an else statement to `if let device = AVCaptureDevice.default(.builtInDualCamera, for: .video, position: .back) { }` and show a toast if no device is found and that is where the error is occurring. On the devices with a problem, it appears it can't find a device. Does anyone know why that would happen?

**CameraService**

```
import Foundation
import AVFoundation
import SwiftUI

class CameraService: ObservableObject {
    var session = AVCaptureSession()
    var delegate: AVCapturePhotoCaptureDelegate?
    var previewLayer = AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer()
    var output = AVCapturePhotoOutput()
    
    @Published var info: AlertInfo?
    
    
    func start(delegate: AVCapturePhotoCaptureDelegate, completion: @escaping (Error?) -> ()) {
        self.delegate = delegate
        checkPermissions(completion: completion)
    }
    
    private func checkPermissions(completion: @escaping (Error?) -> ()) {
        switch AVCaptureDevice.authorizationStatus(for: .video) {
        case .notDetermined:
            AVCaptureDevice.requestAccess(for: .video) { [weak self] granted in
                guard granted else { return }
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    self?.setupCamera(completion: completion)
                }
            }
        case .restricted:
            info = AlertInfo(
                
                id: .restricted,
                title: "Camera Access Restricted",
                message: "We can't open the camera.")
            break
        case .denied:
            info = AlertInfo(
                
                id: .denied,
                title: "Camera Access Denied",
                message: "Please enable camera access by going to Settings > Privacy & Security > Camera")
            break
        case .authorized:
            setupCamera(completion: completion)
        @unknown default:
            info = AlertInfo(
                
                id: .unknown,
                title: "Unknown Error Occurred",
                message: "An unknown error has occurred. Please try again later")
            break
        }
    }
    
    private func setupCamera(completion: @escaping (Error?) -> ()) {
        
        
        do {
            if let device = AVCaptureDevice.default(for: .video) {
                
                self.session.beginConfiguration()
                
                let input = try AVCaptureDeviceInput(device: device)
                
                if self.session.canAddInput(input) {
                    self.session.addInput(input)
                }
                
                if self.session.canAddOutput(output) {
                    self.session.addOutput(output)
                }
                
                self.session.commitConfiguration()
            }

        } catch {
            completion(error)
        }
    }
    
    func capturePhoto() {
                    
        DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background).async {
            if let delegate = self.delegate {
                
                self.output.capturePhoto(with: AVCapturePhotoSettings(), delegate: delegate)
                    DispatchQueue.main.async { Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 0.1, repeats: false) { (timer) in self.session.stopRunning() }
                    }
            }
        }
    }
    
    func retakePhoto() {
        DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background).async {
            self.session.startRunning()
        }
    }
}

struct AlertInfo: Identifiable {
    
    enum AlertType {
        case denied
        case restricted
        case unknown
    }
    
    let id: AlertType
    let title: String
    let message: String
}
```

**CameraView**

```
import Foundation
import UIKit
import SwiftUI
import AVFoundation

struct CameraView: UIViewControllerRepresentable {
    typealias UIViewControllerType = UIViewController
    
    @StateObject var service = CameraService()
    let didFinishProcessingPhoto: (Result<AVCapturePhoto, Error>) -> ()
    
    func makeUIViewController(context: Context) -> UIViewController {
        
        service.start(delegate: context.coordinator) { err in
            if let err = err {
                didFinishProcessingPhoto(.failure(err))
                return
            }
        }
        
        let vc = UIViewController()

        DispatchQueue.global().async {
            service.session.startRunning()
        
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                
                service.previewLayer = AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer(session: service.session)
                service.previewLayer.frame = vc.view.bounds
                service.previewLayer.videoGravity = .resizeAspectFill
                vc.view.layer.addSublayer(service.previewLayer)
                
            }
        }
        return vc
    }
    
    func makeCoordinator() -> Coordinator {
         Coordinator(self, didFinishProcessingPhoto: didFinishProcessingPhoto)
    }
    
    func updateUIViewController(_ uiViewController: UIViewController, context: Context) {
        
    }
    
    class Coordinator: NSObject, AVCapturePhotoCaptureDelegate {
        let parent: CameraView
        private var didFinishProcessingPhoto: (Result<AVCapturePhoto, Error>) -> ()
        
        init(_ parent: CameraView, didFinishProcessingPhoto: @escaping (Result<AVCapturePhoto, Error>) -> ()) {
            self.parent = parent
            self.didFinishProcessingPhoto = didFinishProcessingPhoto
        }
        
        func photoOutput(_ output: AVCapturePhotoOutput, didFinishProcessingPhoto photo: AVCapturePhoto, error: Error?) {
            if let error = error {
                didFinishProcessingPhoto(.failure(error))
                return
            }
            didFinishProcessingPhoto(.success(photo))
        }
    }
}
```

**CustomCameraView**

```
import SwiftUI
import PhotosUI

struct CustomCameraView: View {
    @Environment(\.dismiss) private var dismiss
    @StateObject var service = CameraService()
    @StateObject var viewModel: UploadPostViewModel
    
    var body: some View {
        
        ZStack {
            CameraView(service: service)
            { result in
                switch result {
                case .success(let photo):
                    if let data = photo.fileDataRepresentation() {
                        viewModel.capturedImage = UIImage(data: data)
                    } else {
                        //write error message
                        
                    }
                case .failure(let err):
                    //write error message
                    print(err)
                }
            }
            
            VStack (alignment: .leading) {
                
                Spacer()
                
                HStack {
                    PhotoPickerForPost { result in
                        switch result {
                        case .success(let image):
                            viewModel.capturedImage = image
                        case .failure(let error):
                            //write error message
                            print(error)
                            viewModel.capturedImage = nil
                        }
                    }
                    
                    Spacer()
                    
                    Button {
                        service.capturePhoto()
                    } label: {
                        Image(systemName: "circle")
                            .font(.system(size: 72))
                            .foregroundColor(.white)
                    }
                    Spacer()
                    Rectangle()
                        .foregroundColor(.clear)
                        .frame(width: 32, height: 28)
                }
                .padding()
            }
        }
        .padding(.horizontal, 4)
        .cornerRadius(6)
        .background(.black)
        .alert(item: $service.info, content: { info in

            Alert(title: Text(info.title),
                  message: Text(info.message))
        })
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the other devices which work? I think the issue is near `AVCaptureDevice.default(for: .video)` line. Try to use `AVCaptureDevice.DiscoverySession`.

Comment: The devices it works on that I know of so far are iPhone 12 Pro, iPhone 11 Pro, and iPhone 14 Pro. I tried using DiscoverySession, and I got errors about converting DiscoverySession to AVCaptureDevice. I do agree it probably has to do with that line cause it passes the checkPermissions function... @AliaksandrAndrashuk

Comment: You should have a look at Apple's [AVCam](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/capture_setup/avcam_building_a_camera_app) sample app.